# Initial Velocity and Brakes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> Mathematically investigate and derive a theoretical relationship between a vehicle's initial velocity (the dependent variable) and the length of its skid marks (independent variable).

$$\require{enclose}\begin{align}
v^2&=u^2+2as\\
0&=u^2+2as\\
0&=u^2+2\times-\mu g\times s,\quad as-a=-\mu g\\
0&=u^2-2\mu gs\\
-u^2&=-2\mu gs\\
\frac{-u^2}{-2\mu g}&=-\enclose{horizontalstrike}{2\mu g}s\\
\frac{u^2}{2\mu g}&=s
\end{align}$$

$\therefore$ the Breaking Distance and the Skid Distance $S_B=\dfrac{u^2}{2\mu g}$

I have done the question and I was wondering if I did it correctly. If not, can you tell me where I have gone wrong or what I should do?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all looks good to me except your expression for the acceleration should be $a=-\mu g$, but you have actually used this correctly, just stated it incorrectly!

Comment: Woops, You are correct. Thanks for pointing out that mistake. All fine apart from that?

Comment: Should be yes, do you need to show where you got your expression for $a$ from?

Comment: Our teacher gave it to us, so it's all good. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you also help me with this question please? (Follow the Link). http://imgur.com/bp5rvvU
Thanks

Comment: Something is not correct with the equation that your teacher gave you.  As shown, it is dimensionally incorrect.